# Rails 4 - redirect to correct url after submit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, validation, routes

I have a simple sign up form. It has the url of `/signup` defined in `routes.rb`.

```
match '/signup',  to: 'users#new', via: 'get'
```

The problem is, when I press submit with invalid fields it redirects to `/users`.

My controller action  (scaffolded) looks like this:

```
def create
  @user = User.new(user_params)

  respond_to do |format|
    if @user.save
      format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @user }
    else
      # Here it redirects to /users
      format.html { render action: 'new' }
      format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

What I want is to stay on the same page (with the same url) if the signup fails. Any ideas on what I can do to achieve that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently when the signup fails, you are rendering new action so your url would have path like:

`/users/new`

I suppose you want it to look like `/signup` instead

For doing that, in the `create` action replace

```
format.html { render action: 'new' }
```

With

```
format.html { redirect_to signup_url }
```

This way path would look like `/signup` and action new would be called.

Comment: If I do this I get the following error: `ActionController::UnknownFormat`, do you know why that is?

Comment: @AndersPlanting Check my updated answer. Make sure you update the code like that. Let me know if you still get the error.

Comment: Thanks, now it works. The problem now is the my @user error messages isn't shown, but that's probably another question, unless you have a quick idea?

Answer (score 1):

The reason that the path is redirect to `/users` is because this is the the path of action `create`, there is no redirect if user save failed in action `create`, it just render the `new` view template.

If you want to stay to `/users/new`, you need to redirect to new user path

Comment: Tried to change `render action: 'new'` to `redirect_to signup_url` but I get the following error: `ActionController::UnknownFormat`.

Comment: the action that handle request from signup_url doesn't know how to handle the format(eg. html, js), more info is needed to know why